# Ajax Update Panel Session Time Out issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a GridView control which is inside an AJAX update panel by default session timeout for the user is 20 mins when the user clicks on paging numbers my apps shows a timeout alert. So my question is how to handle timeout issue and redirect the user to the login page in Ajax Update Panel Control.

Comment: This may help: http://forums.asp.net/p/1193501/2058066.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all who have helped me. I have solved the issue below is the source code. UpdatePanel Have 2 Callback Events which gets triggered automatically when updatepanel refreshes. Those 2 events are **add_beginRequest** and **add_endRequest**

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    if (args._error != null)
    {
        if (args._error.name =="Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException")
        {
            alert("Your session has expired");
            args._error.message="Your session has expired";
            args._errorHandled=true;                        
            parent.window.location.href='/asp/login.asp';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```